# How to send a message to everyone at a certain in-game time?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm looking for a way to send a chat message to all players telling them it is nearing night in my local Bedrock Edition server. I have searched Google and Arqade for this, but do not have an answer that isn't either outdated or using plugins. I am, despite my lack of knowledge of the matter, willing to use command blocks if needed.

Here's the message I want to send, in tellraw command format:

`/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§6It's getting late!"}]}`

How can I get it to send at in-game dusk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [daylight sensors](https://minecraftbedrock.fandom.com/wiki/Daylight_Sensor) are for. These blocks send out a redstone signal that has it's power dependent on what time of the day/night it is.

Daylight sensors come in 2 different types: the regular and the inverted.

For your situation, the inverted type is better to use, as it starts sending out redstone signal during dusk. You simply place the sensor, place a 1 block long redstone wire next to it that powers a command block that sends the message to chat. The syntax of a command that would say in chat "Goodnight" would be:

```
/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"Goodnight"}]}
```

For hiding the contraption, I suggest using non-opaque blocks. Lava seems to work just fine for this.

Comment: Daylight sensors would have to be in broad daylight to be effective right? Even if the were inverted, they'd still need to be in sunlight some times to differentiate. This is in a survival world where we want to explore a lot, and I don't want them to see any command blocks behind the scenes. What can I do?

Comment: I see. I'm not very familiar with the Bedrock edition, but I'll try to come up with a solution other than daylight sensors.

Comment: I'm not saying we can't use daylight sensors. I'm just saying I need to hide the daylight sensor, while still picking up the change in light.

Comment: Yeah. The only way I can think of to hide it is putting it under a block that lets daylight trough, maybe a piston or something like that

Comment: Ok, thank you! Could you help me with my other message I want to send when it becomes actual night?
``/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§cIt has become night time!"}]}``

Comment: What do you need hep with? You seem to have the command syntax correct, now you can just lead another, longer redstone wire (8 blocks long is for sunset, 11 is for complete night time) and connect it to the command block

Comment: Thank you! Just needed to know how long the line had to be.