# Minecraft test for time

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a world in Minecraft Pocket Edition that when it is one minute before night time, there are command blocks that test for it and show that on screen, then to you to rooms when it is night time. I can do the second part, but I don’t know how to make it tell you one minute before night. I can't do `/time query` (whatever the time is in ticks).

Comment: Why can't you do `/time query`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a message to everyone at a certain in-game time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352752/how-to-send-a-message-to-everyone-at-a-certain-in-game-time)